# Scala | Create new Lists of 1st, 2nd ,.., nth values of Lists

Tags: scala, list

Given a Scala list of lists:

```
List(List(Some(1),Some(2),Some(3),Some(4)),List(Some(1),Some(2),Some(3),Some(4)),List(Some(1),Some(2),Some(3),Some(4)))
```

How can I create the new list of lists:

```
List(List(Some(1),Some(1),Some(1)),List(Some(2),Some(2),Some(2)),List(Some(3),Some(3),Some(3)),List(Some(4),Some(4),Some(4)))
```

So I want to get the first item of every list (and make a new list), then get the second item of every list (and make a new list) and so on.

I have tried nesting `.maps()` however I don't think that this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `transpose` method

```scala
val a = List(List(Some(1),Some(2),Some(3),Some(4)),List(Some(1),Some(2),Some(3),Some(4)),List(Some(1),Some(2),Some(3),Some(4)))

a.transpose // List(List(Some(1), Some(1), Some(1)), List(Some(2), Some(2), Some(2)), List(Some(3), Some(3), Some(3)), List(Some(4), Some(4), Some(4)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Ron Nagar's solution.

However, since I already implemented something on my own, I thought I would share it.

```
object ListOfListsTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val myList = List(List(Some(1),Some(2),Some(3),Some(4)),List(Some(1),Some(2),Some(3),Some(4)),List(Some(1),Some(2),Some(3),Some(4)))
    println(regroup(myList))
  }

  def regroup[A](list: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = {
    def regroupInner[A](l: List[List[A]], acc: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = {
      val split = l.flatMap{xs =>
        xs match {
          case y::ys => Some((y, ys))
          case Nil => None
        }
      }
      val splitHead = split.map(_._1)
      val splitTail = split.map(_._2)

      splitTail match {
        case Nil =>
          splitHead match {
            case Nil => acc
            case z::zs => splitHead::acc
          }
        case w::ws =>
          regroupInner(splitTail, splitHead::acc)
      }
    }

    regroupInner(list, List()).reverse
  }
}
```